# How to build Memgraph Docker Extension that uses specific version of underlying Docker image?

Tags: memgraphdb

[Memgrpah Docker extension](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension) uses the latest Memgraph Platform image. At the moment, this means that Memgraph Platform 2.8 is used.

I would like to build a Docker Extension that uses Memgraph Platform 2.7. Can that be done?

I've tried `docker build --tag=memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension:2.7.0 .` but this only tags Docker extension with 2.7, it doesn't change the Memgraph Platform that is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a specific version of the Memgraph Platform do the following:

1. Clone the repo - `git clone https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph-docker-extension`
2. Edit `docker-compose.yaml`. Find the line that defines the docker image that is used, e.g. `image: "memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.8.0-memgraph2.8.0-lab2.6.0-mage1.7"` and replace the image name/tag with one that you want. You can find the list of tags at https://hub.docker.com/r/memgraph/memgraph-platform/tags.